# Creating numlink functions in php

Tags: php

Hae .
I have a website where i display data from my website ... I have a very big problem of creating num link php functions. For instance , on click the next numlink for this example url 'http://www.deffsale.com/AllAds/?Ad=Other%20ladys%20Fashion?page=1' it is returning this 'http://www.deffsale.com/AllAds/?page=1' I'm testing it on my local host and have been searching all over the net and up .. I request any person with an idea or a link where i can solve this problem for my site . In addition , i have a mobile version for the same site and i would like to apply the same theory on it .

My code

```
<?php
            require'../../../php/connection.php';


            $dataperpage=12;
            $page_visible=200;

            if(isset($_GET['page'])){
                $pagenum=$_GET['page'];
                $query="select `create_gig_id` from `create_gig`";
                $query_run=mysql_query($query);

                if($num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_run)){
                    $num_rows;
                }
                $user_id=getUserField('account_id');

                $maxpage=ceil($num_rows / $dataperpage);
                $itemfrom=($pagenum-1) * $dataperpage;

                $query="select t1.create_gig_id,t1.gigSubCategory,t1.amount_charge,t1.gig_pic,t1.gig_type,t1.duration,t2.profile_photo,t2.user_name FROM create_gig t1 JOIN user_account t2 ON t2.account_id=t1.account_id where t1.Approve='approved' order by rand() DESC limit $itemfrom,$dataperpage";
                $query_run=mysql_query($query);
                $cols=4;

                echo"<table>";
                do{


                    echo"<tr>";
                        for($i=1;$i<=$cols;$i++){

                            $row=mysql_fetch_array($query_run);

                            if($row){

                                $gig_pic= $row['gig_pic'];
                                $order_type=$row['gigSubCategory'];
                                $create_gig_id = $row['create_gig_id'].'<br><br>';

                                    $duration= $row['duration'];


                                    echo"<td>";

                                    echo"<table>";
                                        echo"<tr valign='top'>";
                                        echo"<b id='charge'>$".$row['amount_charge']."</b>";

                                                echo"<td id='seller_details'>".'<img id="fetch_img"src="../../../uploads/'.$gig_pic.'"height=200>'."";
                                                        $passString=$row['create_gig_id'];
                                                        $gig_id=encrypt($passString);
                                                        //$gig_id=urlencode($encrypted_string);
                                                        $rand=encrypt(rand(34567,345678988));

                                                echo"I will do <font color='blue'><font color='green'><b>".$order_type."</b></font> <br>by &nbsp".$row['user_name']."</font> in ".$duration." days <br><a class='SellerDetails' data-id=".$row['create_gig_id']." href='SellerDetails.php?gig_id=".$gig_id."'>read more >></a>";

                                                echo"</td>";
                                                echo"<td width='200'>".'&nbsp'."</td>";
                                        echo"</tr>";
                                    echo"</table>";
                                                echo"</td>";

                                }else
                                    {
                                        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
                                    }
                            }
                                        echo"</tr>";
                                }while($row);
                    echo"</table>";

                echo"<br><br>";

    numlinks($pagenum,$maxpage,$maxpage,'','');
    }
    ?>
```

Numlink include code

```
<?php

function numlinks($pagenum, $maxpage, $pages_visible, $scriptname="", $get="") {

    echo '<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="t-border"><tr>';
    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        echo '<td class="td-border"><a href="'.page_name(1, $scriptname, $get).'" class="numlinks">&laquo;</a></td>';   // first page
        echo '<td class="td-border"><a href="'.page_name(($pagenum-1), $scriptname, $get).'" class="numlinks">previous</a></td>';   // prev page
    } else {
        echo '<td class="td-border numlinks-inactive">&laquo;</td>';   // first page
        echo '<td class="td-border numlinks-inactive">previous</td>';   // prev page
    }   



    $i=1;
    while ($i <= $pages_visible){
        if ($pagenum-ceil($pages_visible/2) < 0) {  //wenn unterer Bereich
            if ($i == $pagenum) echo '<td class="td-border numhighlight">'.($pagenum).'</td>';
            else echo '<td class="td-border"><a href="'.page_name($i, $scriptname, $get).'" class="numlinks">'.($i).'</a></td>';

        } else if ($pagenum+floor($pages_visible/2) > $maxpage) {  // wenn oberer bereich
            if($maxpage > $pages_visible) $j = $maxpage-$pages_visible+$i;
            else $j = $i;

            if ($j == $pagenum) echo '<td class="td-border numhighlight">'.($pagenum).'</td>';
            else echo '<td class="td-border"><a href="'.page_name($j, $scriptname, $get).'" class="numlinks">'.$j.'</a></td>';


        } else {  // wenn mittlerer bereich
            if ($i == ceil($pages_visible/2)) echo '<td class="td-border numhighlight">'.($pagenum).'</td>';
            else {
                $j = $pagenum-ceil($pages_visible/2)+$i;
                echo '<td class="td-border"><a href="'.page_name($j, $scriptname, $get).'" class="numlinks">'.$j.'</a></td>';
            }
        }
        if ($i == $maxpage) break;
        $i++;
    }




    if ($pagenum < $maxpage){
        echo '<td class="td-border"><a href="'.page_name(($pagenum+1), $scriptname, $get).'" class="numlinks">next</a></td>';  // next page
        echo '<td class="td-border"><a href="'.page_name($maxpage, $scriptname, $get).'" class="numlinks">&raquo;</a></td>';   // last page
    } else {
        echo '<td class="td-border numlinks-inactive">next</td>';   // first page
        echo '<td class="td-border numlinks-inactive">&raquo;</td>';   // prev page
    }   

    echo '</tr></table>';
}

function page_name($nr, $scriptname, $get="") {
    $scriptname.='?page='.$nr;
    if ($get != '') $scriptname.='&'.$get;
    return $scriptname;
}

?>
```

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: You cannot use **?** character in your URL more than once. Replace any further question marks with **&** character.